# axios Authorization headers only working with get requests

Tags: javascript, api, http, authorization, axios

I have a simple api endpoint for sharing posts `/api/v1/posts/{id}/share` that requires authentication with a bearer token.

I try to send a POST request like the following and it responds with a 401

```
axios.post(`/api/v1/posts/${id}/share`,
        {
        "headers": {
                "Authorization":"Bearer "+token,
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
        });
```

only when i changed it to accept a GET on the backend and changed the code to this did it work

```
axios.get(`/api/v1/posts/${id}/share`,
        {
        "headers": {
                "Authorization":"Bearer "+token,
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
        });
```

I tested my endpoints with an http client (insomnia) so the problem does seem to be with axios. why is this happening and how can I solve it?

the server I'm using is apache and the backend framework is laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is: `axios.post` and `axios.get` have different syntax -- the 2nd parameter represents "config" in `axios.get`, but represents "data" in `axios.post`. That's why it works in GET but fails in POST.

According to axios [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), these 2 syntax are:

> axios.get(url[, config])
>
> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

Thus, when you send HTTP POST request with code:

```
axios.post(`/api/v1/posts/${id}/share`,
        {
        "headers": {
                ...
            },
        });
```

The request is sent, with HTTP **body** as `{"header":{...}}` -- no request header is configured.

To make it work with `axios.post`, the `headers` config object should be passed as the 3rd parameter. Such as:

```
axios.post(`/api/v1/posts/${id}/share`,
        {}, // or whatever data you want to send.
        {
        "headers": {
                ...
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

so I solved this by using a different syntax

```
const options = {
        method:"post",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization":token,
            "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        url:`/api/v1/posts/${id}/share`
    };

    axios(options);
```

I honestly cannot say what changed but here you go for anyone that sees this.